# Spring hibernate using maven

Tags: spring, maven

I am using maven for spring hibernate , everything is fine but the database is not getting created in my db, this is my pom.xml file. Tomcat is not showing any error in the console , spring is working but hibernate is not working what could be the error ??

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven1</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Configuration which allows JUnit tests to be placed in the same folder as java files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
       <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
             **                 HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES                           ** 
             ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
             **                 OTHER DEPENDENCIES                               ** 
             ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
  <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
  <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
            ** TEST DEPENDENCIES 
        ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Where is your database configuration??

Comment: "but the database is not getting created in my db" - do you mean that you expect that your Hibernate entities will autogenerate tables and such in your db? In this case you should find the db configuration file (it should contain the string "hibernate.connection.url"), and add the property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" with the value "update".